# Different letter size when using uppercase letters

Tags: css, web, browser, fonts

we're trying to use work sans, but the letters seems to have different heights when uppercase. Same problem on different browsers. But the text seems to look perfectly fine when zoomed. The website is made on Wordpress, so utf-8 and etc. goes without saying

Any idea why it's acting like that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you link the page that this occurs in? Also, please provide the relevant CSS

Comment: can you host your website and show it there?

Comment: As well as the obvious "Show an example" mentioned above, have you tried different browsers? Font rendering can vary quite a bit depending on browser and even OS that you're running on.

Comment: As the text is fine when zoomed this is likely a platform issue with font rendering at small sizes. Can you tell us what OS you are on, and could you also share the CSS, and also the exact text (Unicode code points could matter)? Btw, you can always try at https://typecast.com/preview/google/Work%20Sans, there your text looks just fine for me.

Comment: The website is in development and I'm not allowed to share it with anyone :) It's being made in Wordpress so it would he hard to exclude only the css that effects this particular part.. I know i'm looking for help but it's not possible to give wider information :) CSS looks something like this http://i.imgur.com/JKlxcUn.jpg?1

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle where this problem occurs? And could you do list about browsers you have tested. also could you tell us browser versions too. Thanks

Comment: Maybe related to the font quality, try a different font-family and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is my browsers and OS rendering 14 px work sans font with font-weight property. If i change the font size to 15 or 13 everything is fine on every browser with every font-weight. Result: switched to other font.